# Is it possible to allow users to log int but not to register using AWS cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am developing a webpage that requires employees to authenticate (with email and password) in order to access content in said website. (Not anyone can access the webpage, only employees that have a correct email/password combination)

Since I am developing the webpage using AWS (API Gateway, Lambda, RDS, EC2, etc.) I decided to use Cognito for the authentication.

The problem is that Cognito seems to always allow users to register a new account and then access the webpage with that newly created account. This is something that I want to avoid since I want only employees to have access to the webpage.

Is it possible to allow users to log int but not to register using AWS Cognito?

Is there another solution using Cognito besides not allowing users to register? Maybe allowing anyone to register but only allowing certain emails from the Cognito control panel?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allow only administrators to create new user in Cognito Pool:

- Via [Cloud Formation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-admincreateuserconfig.html) template
- Via AWS Console - under general settings there is `User sign ups allowed?` option

[image: AWS Console]